# How to use a loader to process an npm module built with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I have a project built with React and JavaScript, and I want to use an npm module built with TypeScript. However, I am having trouble configuring my project to compile the TypeScript code from the module. I am getting the following error:

```
Module parse failed: The keyword 'interface' is reserved (7:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
```

I think if I could add a loader to compile the TypeScript code from the module, it would work.

I have already installed TypeScript in my project and partially configured it to work with TypeScript and JavaScript. I did a small test, and it works. I even tried copying the code from the TypeScript module into my src folder, and it works. But I don't know how to make it work the normal way from the node_modules folder.

Do you have any ideas?

These are the dependencies I have installed in my project:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "module-made-in-typescript": "module-made-in-typescript",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
}
```

My tsconfig.json file is:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "jsx": "react",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*", "./node_modules/module-made-in-typescript/src/**/*"]
}
```

I don't have a webpack configuration file, and I don't know how to add one to an existing React project. I think that if I could add one, I could configure the loader from there, but I don't know.

Thanks for your help! :D

Comment: I would say that who's in the wrong here is the NPM package.  You may use TypeScript to write NPM packages, no problem.  The mistake, in my opinion, is to have packaged said TypeScript as opposed to a transpilation of it.  If you made the package, you should package the resultant JavaScript.  If the package is not yours, see if you can contact the package owner.

Answer (score 0):

While you *did* add your library path in `tsconfig.include`, you also have to use the [`exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude) option to avoid your entire `node_modules` folder from being excluded from transpilation by default:

> Specifies an array of filenames or patterns that should be skipped when resolving `include`.
>
> [...]
>
> Default: node_modules, bower_components, jspm_packages, outDir

Another hack you may try, consists in using a symlink placed in your `src` folder and pointing to your library within `node_modules`. Then import through that symlink, as if it were actually part of your source code, instead of a published package.

---

That being said, the published package should normally provide an already transpiled version, and you should not have to directly use its TypeScript source.